# Android: on swipe switch between Views / Activities / Fragments

Tags: android, view, android-activity, swipe, fragment

I'm implementing a chat application. The user is able to have multiple chats open simultaneously, and I want to allow him to switch between these chats with swiping left or right. Like e.g. in the gtalk app. I'm not sure what's the best way to implement this:

- Should I use one Activity per chat? If yes, how do I select the correct activity instance for switching to the next chat?
- Should I use only one Activity instance and several views and switch between them like in [this example](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)?
- Or should I use Fragments and switch between them? Does the FragmentManager provide a way to pick the right Fragment instance for switching between them?

What do you think is the best solution, and why? Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the following Android Dev blog post about using ViewPager in the Android Compatibility Package to implement the swipe functionality you're looking for:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

The recommended approach is most likely to use a Fragment for the chat history and text input field as this will give you the most flexibility across devices.